# Add library to Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github, import

I want to add [this](https://github.com/bookwormat/segcontrol) repository to my Android Studio project and I tried multiple dependencies but it just doesn't work. Any help, guys ?

My build.gradle (app) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24+'
    compile 'com.7heaven.widgets:segmentcontrol:1.16'
    compile 'at.bookworm:segcontrol:1' //THIS GUY IS MY PROBLEM
}
```

My build.gradle (app) file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find this project in jcenter.

Comment: Did you try compile 'com.github.bookwormat:segcontrol:master-SNAPSHOT'? If not why have you included jitpack repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Download the Library from Github.
2. Unzip.
3. In Android Studio go to File > New > Import Module and set the directory to "Library" folder inside "segcontrol-master".

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me:

Open your project in Android Studio
Download the library (using Git, or a zip archive to unzip)
Go to File > Project Structure >Click on the more on the left green "+" button > import Module dependency in to your workplace.
Then add that module to your project.
Select "your Library"

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve with this approach is to include a jCenter library via maven. But this repository is not uploaded to jCenter. You should be able to include the lib by downloading the sources and import the lib module or create a sysmlink to the libmodule in you project's root.